# how to create a multiple checkbox using ionic tree view ionic 4 && angular

Tags: angular, ionic4

```
`[ { "id":1, "name":"features" }, { "id":2, "name":"Add", "parentID":1 }, { "id":3, "name":"Remove", "parentID":1 }, { "id":9, "name":"Update", "parentID":1 }, { "id":11, "name":"UpdateDel", "parentID":9 }, { "id":27, "name":"Add", "parentID":2 }, { "id":28, "name":"master" } ]

in ts file 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import library
import { IonicTreeViewModule } from 'ionic-tree-view';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // Specify library as an import
    IonicTreeViewModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }`
```

how to create a multiple checkbox using ionic tree view ionic 4 && angular 
This library is used to generate a treeview from an object list.
[image: the response like this]

Comment: Did you achieve as the image or want to achieve it since you question is not 100% clear and nay have 2 faces

Comment: tq for replaying.  i am not achieved the image.i want response like as that mentioned image.

Comment: With the array you added, what did you get? Add a capture of the carrent output for this array you added?

Comment: i am getting same array of as the mention but when selected one of the node the total tree was selected